# Struts2 - Result generated by append tag cannot be iterated multiple times

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Here is the code snippet:

```
<s:set value="{1,2,3}" var="list1" />
<s:set value="{4,5,6}" var="list2" />
<s:append var="list3">
    <s:param value="#list1" />
    <s:param value="#list2" />
</s:append> 
<s:iterator value="#list3">
    <s:property />
</s:iterator>
<hr />
<s:iterator value="#list3">
    <s:property />
</s:iterator>
<hr />
```

Here is the result:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The second `<s:iterator>` tag does not work at all, what happened to `#list3`, is `#list3` now an empty list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#list3` is not a list it is a reference to appended iterator (instance of `AppendIteratorFilter`). This is how `<s:append>` tag works. It will remove iteratable sources after iteration. You can call `hasNext()` method on appended iterator to see if it has more elements in it. And `next()` method to get the next element.

```
<s:iterator value="#list3">
    <s:property />
    <s:property value="#list3.hasNext()"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Well there is `merge` tag also :) http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/merge.html.

Comment: Never used that too... and, most likely, never will :)

Comment: They're so easy to abuse--for real fun there's `generator` and `subset`, too :/ I've used them exactly once in real life.